# How to stop TypeORM from adding indeces from embedded entities

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, typeorm

I’m using TypeORM with MongoDB, and I have an Entity which has a `@Column` which embeds another Entity.

The issue I’m facing is that it’s also inheriting the embedded entity’s Indices, and I don’t want it to automatically add them to the entity that’s embedding it. e.g:

```js
@Entity()
class Foo {
  @Column()
  @Index()
  uuid: string

  // some other columns and entity methods of Foo, omitted for brevity...
}

@Entity()
class Bar {
  @Column()
  @Index()
  uuid: string


  @Column(() => Foo)
  foo: Foo

  // More columns and entity methods of Bar
}
```

...will result in the Bar collection having a foo.uuid index.

**How do I stop this?**

P.S. I edited the original post to reflect that both Foo and Bar are separate collections in Mongo, each one has it's own UUID field and `Bar` embeds `Foo`. Foo, aside from having its own collection is also denormalised within Bar.

However, I want to prevent Foo's index being put on the Bar collection.

Comment: There is no "Bar collection" here, just a 1 to 1 mapping and thus the key.

Comment: @AluanHaddad edited my original post. Both Foo and Bar are separate collections, but Bar embeds (and denormalizes) Foo. However, when doing so I don't want Foo's index to be placed on the Bar collection.